# Using rvest to scrape returns an empty list

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to scrape the song names from the players at the top of archive.org's live music pages, I'm currently looking at [this page](https://archive.org/details/gd73-02-15.sbd.hall.1580.sbeok.shnf).

Here's my code:

```
songs <- read_html("https://archive.org/details/gd73-06-10.sbd.hollister.174.sbeok.shnf") 
    %>% html_nodes('#jw6__list .ttl') %>% html_text()
```

songs returns character(empty), and if I leave off the html_text(), it returns a list of 0.  I'm not sure why this isn't accessing the text, or how I can do such a thing.  Thanks.

Comment: Searching through the source I could not find a `ttl` class nor an id `jw6__list`. There was though a class `item-ttl` and an id `jw6`

Comment: I had just been using SelectorGadget, but after looking in the source I found what I was looking for using `.container-ia script`.  Thanks!